# How to access already provided rest api in magento

Tags: rest, magento

I am a completely new in Magento. I can say that i am not much familiar with file structure and flow also. My current task is rest web-service.
These steps i have followed.

1. I have created role and user in system > webservice. and also created key and secret key.
2. Than i am hitting this url

   ```
   www.my-magento-store.com/api/rest/products
   ```

But still its showing me 404 Page not found. Any one can tell me step by step process with folder structure, how can i use already provided rest api service and how can i create new service. Treat me as fresher.

Please excuse me for bad English. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$allCategories = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'category.tree'); // Get all categories.
```

Run this from your root of magento you will get the result.